# IP subnets - two subnets?

Tags: ip, iptables

I've tried looking at a lot of resources but I cannot figure out how I can express.

```
5.248.*.*
```

in subnet form. I know how I would do 5.248.1.0/24, but what about two subnets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not talking about two subnets, but rather a B-class subnet containing 16-bits, i.e.

```
5.248.0.0/16
```